# Automate Space Creation in alfresco using Space Template

Tags: templates, alfresco, space

I'm new to Alfresco.I need to automate the process of space creation when a new space is created.I define the template inside space template folder in Data Dictionary.But i do not how to automate the application of this template under User Homes folder.

I'm looking any one of this options.

Option 1: Create Rule that apply the space template to the new space that is created under a particular parent.

Option 2:I'm using OpenCMIS API.If through OpenCMIS if i can create the pass the template object to createfolder function and apply the template.

Please let me is it possible to do the requirement through any of the above options.

Thanks
Shyam

Comment: Just to clarify, The concept of space templates, as far as I know is only valid in Alfresco Explorer out of the box? Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think in the very latest versions of Alfresco (4.2d+) that this is now available in Share. As billerby said, previously this was only possible in Explorer. If you are using earlier versions, then this addon can give you the possibility of creating a space from a template in share:

https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/custom-views-space-templates-share

Answer (score 0):

In your rule; add the aspect cm:templatable to your space and then set the property cm:template as the NodeRef of the template you want to apply to the space.